# How to Parse the JSON response which contains the two arraylist

Tags: android, arrays, json, parsing

I am having the response of one of webservice to get the feeds list and in that response i am getting the two array with the same name. 
The problem is that i am not able get the details of the inner array i.e. "ProfileName", "ImageUrl" etc..

I have tried the json parsing.

Below is the response of JSON:

> ```
>  {"Status":true,
> "result":
>     [
>         {"result":  [
>             {"ProfileName":"followers5","ImageUrl":"http:\/\/192.168.0.1\/webservice2\/uploads\/81.png","Likes":3,"Hearts":2},
>             {"ProfileName":"followers5","VideoUrl":"http:\/\/192.168.0.1\/webservice2\/uploads\/81.mp4","Likes":0,"Hearts":0}
>             ]}
>         ,{"result":[
>             {"ProfileName":"followers6","ImageUrl":"http:\/\/192.168.0.1\/webservice2\/uploads\/82.png","Likes":0,"Hearts":2},
>             {"ProfileName":"followers6","VideoUrl":"http:\/\/192.168.0.1\/webservice2\/uploads\/82.mp4","Likes":0,"Hearts":0}
>             ]}
>     ]
>  }
> ```

I have tried as below:

> ```
>     class feedtask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
>     @Override
>     protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
>         Httputils getmethod = new Httputils();
>         try {
>             result = getmethod.Getrequest("feeds.php?uid=76");
>             System.out.println("Feeds Result--->" + result);
>             JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(result);
>             JSONArray ja = jobj.getJSONArray("result");
>             for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
>                 for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
>                     JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(j);
>                     abcd.add(jo.getString("ProfileName"));
>                     System.out.println("Profile Name--->"
>                             + jo.getString("ProfileName"));
>                 }
>             }
>         } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
>             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         } catch (IOException e) {
>             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         } catch (JSONException e) {
>             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
>         return result;
>     }
>   }
> ```

Please help me out to get the details of the second array.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Using GSON Library you can easily convert it to in Java Class. But from your Json response I suggest you to just redesign json response. So its make easy for you to handle it in one array list..

Comment: @user370305 can you tell me what changes needs to be in json response ?

Comment: Just seen as per your JSON response Make an Array of result with only one row like `ProfileName` which one is unique and other fields in same row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 try{
            JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(response);
            if(responseJson.has("result")){
                JSONArray resultJsonArr = responseJson.getJSONArray("result");
                for(int i=0; i<resultJsonArr.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject resultInstanceJson = resultJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
                    if(resultInstanceJson.has("result")){
                        JSONArray resultArr = resultInstanceJson.getJSONArray("result");
                        for(int j=0; j<resultArr.length(); j++){
                            JSONObject jsonResult = resultArr.getJSONObject(j);
                            String profileNAme = jsonResult.getString("ProfileName");
                            String imageUrl = "", videoUrl = "";
                            //image url
                            if(jsonResult.has("ImageUrl")){
                                imageUrl = jsonResult.getString("ImageUrl");
                            }
                            //video url
                            if(jsonResult.has("VideoUrl")){
                                videoUrl = jsonResult.getString("VideoUrl");
                            } 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: This is fine but i am getting the two separate urls for Image and video in response so how can i differentiate that and get the value for both in same variable ?

Comment: Thanks its working but its not getting the second arraylist result. :(

Comment: You have to save it into array list. Could you please check through printing the logcat data in DDMS.

Comment: Its only showing the first array result for "follower5". Its not parsing second array result for "follower6".

Comment: I've checked and it's parsing all the data correctly, if you have still problem in parsing then please send me your code lines.

Answer (score 4):

```
try
    {
        JSONObject _JSONResponse=new JSONObject(response);
        String status=_JSONResponse.getString("Status");
        JSONArray _ArrayResponse=_JSONResponse.getJSONArray("result");

        for(int i=0;i<_ArrayResponse.length();i++)
        {
            JSONArray object=_ArrayResponse.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("result");

            for(int j=0;j<object.length();j++)
            {
                JSONObject jObject=object.getJSONObject(j);
                ProfileName=jObject.getString("ProfileName") ;
                VideoUrl=jObject.optString("VideoUrl") ;
                Likes=jObject.optString("Likes") ;
                Hearts=jObject.optString("Hearts") ;
                Log.i(TAG,ProfileName +" "+VideoUrl +"  "+Likes+"   " +Hearts);
            }   
        }
    }
    catch(JSONException e){Log.e(TAG,e.toString());}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);

            JSONArray innerResult = jo.getJSONArray("result");
            int size = innerResult.legth();
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                JSONObject innerJo = innerResult.getJSONObject(j);
                abcd.add(innerJo.getString("ProfileName"));

            }
        }
```

Edit:

```
 public class InfoHolder {

  public String profileName;   
  public String imageUrl;
  public String videUrl;
```

}

```
 for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
          InfoHolder holder = new InfoHolder();
          JSONObject innerJo = innerResult.getJSONObject(j);
          // the same for imageUrl and videoUrl
           holder.profileName =  innerJo.getString("ProfileName");
          abcd.add(holder);

  }
```

of course you have to change from String to InfoHolder your abcd collectio

Comment: This is fine but i am getting the two separate urls for Image and video in response so how can i differentiate that and get the value for both in same variable ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 try {
        result = getmethod.Getrequest("feeds.php?uid=76");
        System.out.println("Feeds Result--->" + result);
        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray ja = jobj.getJSONArray("result");
        for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(j);

                JSONArray resultJA = jo.getJSONArray("result");

                for(int k=0;k< resultJA.length();k++){

                      JSONObject jo_inside = resultJA.getJSONObject(k); 

                      String profileName = jo_inside.getString("ProfileName");

                      //use optString on JSONOBject. it will return empty String if that key does not exists or else the value u want. it won't give any exceptions.

                      String ImageURL = jo_inside.optString("ImageUrl");
                      String VideoURL = jo_inside.optString("VideoUrl"); 

                  }
             }
        }
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
  }
```

}

Comment: This is working but i am getting the two separate urls for Image and video in response so how can i differentiate that and get the value for both in same variable ?

Comment: ok. now check the updated answer. you are suppose to use optString on the JSONObject. Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Its only showing the first array result for "follower5". Its not parsing second array result for "follower6".

Comment: did you place your code inside for(int k=0;k< resultJA.length();k++){ ... } . please verify whether u have three for loops.

Comment: Yes i have placed the code properly as you have done. My code also having 3 loops.

Answer (score 0):

You do

```
for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
```

ok for the first array now you need to get the array inside each cells of the first

For example :

```
JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);

JSONArray ja2 = jo.getJSONArray("result");
```

**then and only then** you do the second loop

Maybe this answer isn't complete but the idea is here